# How to get sum of table a and sum of table b with multiple rows

Tags: sql, firebird

I have two tables:

table1 as a

| id | date | customer | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-08 | a | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-04-08 | a | 3 |

table2 as b

| id | orderid | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 60 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 |

Now I want to have the date, customer and the sum of amount from table1 and the sum of money from table2. That means, the result should look like this:

| date | customer | amount | money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-08 | a | 5 | 140 |

But with the following query I get an amount of 10:

```sql
 select
      a.date,
      a.customer,
      sum(b.money) as money,       
      sum(a.amount) as amount
  from table1 a
    left join table2 b on a.id = b.orderid   
  group by date, customer
```

I don't know, how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky.  You need to aggregate *before* joining:

```
select a.date, a.num_customer, a.a_amount, b.b_amount
from (select a.date, count(*) as num_customer, sum(a.amount) as a_amount
      from table1 a
      group by a.date
     ) a left join
     (select a.date, sum(b.amount) as b_amount
      from table1 a join
           table2 b
           on a.id = b.orderid
      group by a.date
     ) b
     on a.date = b.date;
```

An alternative method is to aggregate the second table by `orderid` first and then join and aggregate again:

```
select a.date, count(*) as num_customer, sum(a.amount),
       sum(b.b_amount)
from table1 a left join
     (select b.orderid, sum(b.amount) as b_amount
      from table2 b
      group by b.orderid
     ) b
     on a.id = b.orderid
group by a.date
```